# Given the differential equation: $\frac{dy}{dt} = (y-2)(y-5)^2$ sketch phase line and identify equilibrium

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am  trying to sketch the phase line and identify equilibrium and I am getting both solutions to be `unstable` , where I think the upper solution has to be `stable` and the lower one should be `unstable`

> a) Sketch the phase line diagram for $\frac{dy}{dt} = (y-2)(y-5)^2$
>
> b) Identify each equilibrium solutions as stable or unstable. Sketch the solutions corresponding to $y(0) = 3$

This is what I have:
[image]

How would you do this?

Comment: If this is homework, please mark it as such.

Comment: Could you tell what you have tried and done up to now ?

Comment: Draw the directions on the lines

Comment: @Amzoti did you just read that from my pic or you actually did the problem so you came to a conclusion ?

Comment: @Amzoti I got marked wrong by my professor...this was a question on my exam...no freaking way!!!

Comment: I said that they were both unstable, and I got marked wrong for the upper one

Comment: yes, the problem is exactly what I wrote!...omg

Comment: please please yes I would love that...I will talk to him!

Comment: I cannot believe this...I have the same thing as yours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a direction field for your problem.

It has many initial points included, plus direction. Notice that in one case, we have points leaving and in the other we approach from one side, but leave from the other.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for taking the time to help me

Comment: even better, it shows the problem on there

Comment: Ahhh! My eyes have missed your phase portraits!